# App Linking not working on testing environment

Tags: android, applinks, android-app-links

I am trying to implement app linking in my application. When I open the app I have a login screen with a login button. This login button when is pressed goes in browser for web login and then it is redirect into app. I want I open the application directly in this moment but deep linking is shows a dialog.

The json file is correct located at `https://my_domain/.well-known/assetlinks.json`and it's `Content-Type` is `application/json` .

My manifest file contains everything is needed for app linking:

```
 <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
      android:host="myhost"
      android:pathPrefix="/auth"
      android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:scheme="http"/>
```

In Android Studio in logs I get  `SingleHostAsyncVerifier`:

```
Verification result: checking for a statement with source b <
  a: "https://host.de"
>
, relation delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls, and target a <
  a <
    a: "BE:32:...:17"
  >
  b: "my_app_package"
>
 --> false.
```

and `IntentFilterVerifier` logs :

```
 Verification 172 complete. Success:false. Failed hosts:my_host.
```

The result of `adb shell dumpsys package d` is :

```
Package: my_app_package
Domains: my_domain
Status:  ask
```

I can not verify `https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://web-site&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls` because my site is not public, it is not a production link and I get `Timeout Error` because of this. Could this be the problem?

Comment: It's mention in the documentation that it can't work if it's not accessible to the public


> Do not publish your app with dev/test URLs in the manifest file that may not be accessible to the public (such as any that are accessible only with a VPN). A work-around in such cases is to configure build variants to generate a different manifest file for dev builds.

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#publish-json

Comment: @RenaudBoulard I configured build variants and I have different manifest file for each build but it is not implemented yet on product build variant. The assertlinks.json is not on production website, it is only on testing website which is not public.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the similar questions ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41945666/5093606 Maybe SSL certificate on your test environment is not valid ?

Comment: Looks more like a comment

Comment: The certificate is valid. I forgot to mention this.